# Building linux application through Vmware

Tags: linux, build-process, vmware, compilation, redhat

I used to develop using Visual Studio on windows... (C++)

we recently migrated our app to linux (red-hat) , and currently each employee is building his own app is his own virtual machine using Vmware. out native OS is still Windows.

At first, it seemed that building using g++ was faster then using VS compiler, however, after some time, it seems like it tured out to be pretty slow. Is it beacuse we're using Vmware ?
are there things we can do to accelerate the building process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ is not a speed daemon, but it performs well.  Yes, a VM can have unsteady performance, especially on disk access.  You can always try [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) to avoid recompiling the parts you don't need to.

Or, ditch VMWare (and windows underneath) and do it all on Linux.  either with a dedicated build box, or on your own machine.  if you *have to have* a full featured GUI for writing, [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) is quite up to the task (no, it's not tied to only writing Qt applications).

Answer (score 2):

I never really noticed that g++ was slower than VS or the opposite, but there is ways to make g++ go a lot faster.

- [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) for instance. I tried it and it really speeds up the compilation.

  > ccache is a compiler cache. It speeds up recompilation of C/C++ code by caching previous compilations and detecting when the same compilation is being done again
- If you're working on a multicore machine you probably want to do multiprocess compilation, if you're using make you can do `make -jX` where X is your number of cores. *Note you'll have to enable multicore on your virtual machines.*
- Disable compiler optimizations.

That said, whatever you do, compilation on a virtual machine wont be as efficient as compilation on a real machine.